# Prospective means future-looking, retrospective means past-looking. What means present-looking?

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

This is actually two questions. One: is there a word that means present-looking? And: if there isn't, what should the neologism be? Spective? Conspective?

Note that although this is a serious question, it is mostly for the purpose of writing a pithy or facetious sentence. For instance,

> Grants are deceitful—they're written as if they're prospective, but they're usually retrospective or conspective.

Comment: Literal;ly, [***circumspective***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/circumspective) means "looking all around" - but figuratively speaking, being ***here, present*** has close associations with being "watchful, circumspective".

Comment: What is the overall intended meaning of the sentence? I'm not sure what you mean by "prospective" and "retrospective" in context.

Comment: Note that your second question (asking people to coin a neologism) is usually considered off-topic here.

Comment: _Circumspect_, no _-ive_ necessary. But it describes behavior, not recollection or prediction.

Comment: @alphabet If I understand it, they're saying that grants are based on what the applicant has done in the past or present, not what they're expected to do in the future.

Comment: I assume that by 'grants' in the sample sentence you mean **applications** for (research) grants (using the term in that way may be common in some circles, but is likely to be confusing to those outside them).

Comment: Do you specifically want something ending "spective"? There are [a lot of words that would fit](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/current), but none matching that pattern.

Comment: Not sure how you define _facetious_, but _instaspective_ might do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

To cover both the past-time and present-time cases, you could say that the grants are approved (or awarded) ***ex post facto.*** [As Merriam-Webster explains,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ex%20post%20facto) "approval for a project that's given *ex post facto*" means approval given "after the project already has been begun or completed."

Comment: If *ex post facto* would do for the OP's purposes, then *retrospective* would do as well; their meanings are essentially the same.

Comment: I think this has kind of gotten the gist. They're trying to say that the work has either been done or is in progress. I think "ex post facto" implies that it's completed.

Comment: @jsw29 "Ex post facto" does not mean the same as "retrospective." It means that the approval (or awarding) happened after *something.* That "something" is unspecified but typically means "after the event you would expect it to precede," which in this case is the start (not the completion) of the work.

Comment: Yes, but *retrospective* means looking backwards at something, some fact which needs to be specified separately, and that implies that the time from which we are looking at it is after it. What makes *ex post facto* arguably work for the OP's purposes is that you are allowing the relevant fact that is referred to by *ex post facto* to be the **beginning** of the project, which is independent of your choice of that phrase. If that works, then *retrospective* also works, in so far as an application that is made while the project is under way is looking backwards at the beginning of the project.

Comment: @jsw29 "Retrospective" typically (I think) refers to "looking back on the past"; it suggests that the work related to the grant occurred entirely in the past, as a whole that one can look back on when the grant is approved (compare: nobody holds a "retrospective" on work that is incomplete). "Ex post facto" suggests that the grant was approved after something else that one would expect it to have preceded; this will likely be interpreted as referring to the start of the work, not necessarily to the work as a whole.